# Find element via adjacent label using XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I was having trouble figuring out the XPATH of the following. There are several other elements with similar attributes (including ID's, but it is not my page), and the only way to ensure the correct element is selected is to get it via its adjacent label, "Copyright". This is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">Copyright :</div>
    <div id="container-id" class="field" >2011 Homeland Ent</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">Another Label :</div>
    <div id="container-id" class="field" >Another Entry</div>
</div>
```

Note that due to the malformed HTML,`//*[@id="container-id"]` would not be sufficient here. What would be the correct XPATH to get the text "2011 Homeland Ent"?

Comment: Can you provide either the full HTML or an example URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this perhaps (I wasn't sure if the "Copyright" text was part of the search, included it anyway

```
//*[@class="label" and starts-with(., "Copyright")]/following-sibling::*[@id="container-id"]
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like each `row` contains a single `label`/`field` pair. If that's true, then a shorter, simpler expression (that doesn't require `following-sibling`) is possible:

```
//*[div[@class='label' and starts-with(., 'Copyright')]]/div[@id='container-id']
```

Answer (score 0):

use this xpath , it will work

```
//div[text()="Copyright :"]/parent::node()/div[@id="container-id"]/text()
```